# How to include both Agda and Isabelle code in the same latex file?

Tags: latex, isabelle, agda

I am creating presentation slides using beamer, and on the slides I want to include pieces of code from Agda and Isabelle standard libraries. All I can find online is generating latex from Agda (lagda) or from Isabelle (document preparation). I want to go the other way, as my slides will have code from different systems. 
I can still use lstlisting or verbatim, but I would rather not copy-paste and reformat code.

I would prefer to have something like including line numbers from files, or maybe code between tags

Comment: I'd suggest using [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings) as you already mentioned, and let it format the code for you. You can define your own `lstlistings` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the [`catchfilebetweentags`](https://ctan.org/pkg/catchfilebetweentags?lang=en) package: given two files `IsabelleCode.tex` and `AgdaCode.tex` generated by the respective LaTeX backends of each language, you can capture the code between an opening tag `%<*TAGNAME>` and a closing tag `%</TAGNAME>` in either file by using the appropriate directive e.g.:

```
\ExecuteMetaData[IsabelleCode.tex]{TAGNAME}
\ExecuteMetaData[AgdaCode.tex]{TAGNAME}
```

Comment: Does this package compiles the agda/isabelle source code every time the latex file is compiled?

Comment: No. It does not know anything about Agda / Isabelle. You have to write a sensible Makefile to organise your dependencies and rebuild the .tex files when the source Isabelle / Agda is modified.

Answer (score 1):

With `\lstinputlisting` from the `listings` package, you can directly include code from the source file. Optionally you can specify the start and end line numbers

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\lstinputlisting[firstline=1,lastline=7,language=C]{duck.C}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\lstinputlisting[firstline=1,lastline=7]{test.agada}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\lstinputlisting[firstline=1,lastline=7]{test.isabelle}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if Agda or Isabelle is supported?

Comment: @ymmagdi Even if not, one can create styles for every language, or just use the default settings

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was just thinking maybe I can get away without defining them myself :)

Comment: Syntax highlighting in Agda is informed by the scope checker. Defining your own style will not give you the same level of information.

Answer (score 0):

At least for Agda, you can render individual `.lagda` modules into LaTeX. If you can do the same with Isabelle's pretty-printer, you should be then able to write toplevel LaTeX by hand, and then import (parts of) the Agda and Isabelle-generated LaTeX where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can you import parts of a latex file? I know about \include and \input, but I am unaware if either of them allows importing parts of the file